# Linq Query to Group By Multiple Columns But Get Additional Properties

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a table with many duplicate records. How can I use a C# Linq query to group by multiple fields but also get the ID of the distinct record.

For example: I have a Store table that looks like this

```
Store
-----
ID, StoreName, Address1

1, CVS, 123 Main Street
2, CVS, 123 Main Street
3, CVS, 456 Main Street
```

I want to group by storeName then by address1, but also get the ID of the first distinct (storeName and address1) record.

I only want these two records:

```
1, CVS, 123 Main Street
3, CVS, 456 Main Street
```

I tried using an anonymous object but can't figure out how to get the ID without also grouping by ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `GroupBy` in LINQ, you get an enumerable of a class which implements interface [`IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb344977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - the `TElement` representing the individual, and original, elements that have been grouped.

Therefore you would group like so

```
 var grouped = myList.GroupBy(x => new {x.StoreName,x.Address1});
```

Which would give you an enumerable list of `IGrouping<anonymous,Store>` (Assuming the original object was called `Store`). The `anonymous` is an anonymous object with 2 properties `StoreName` and `Address1`.

Now, each item in the enumerable is *itself* enumerable of `Store`, and you can treat that exactly as you would any other enumerable - you can take the `First().ID` if you wish, and you could project the whole lot back out to an enumerable if thats what you want

```
var result = myList.GroupBy(x => new {x.StoreName,x.Address1});
                   .Select(g => new {
                                  g.Key.StoreName, 
                                  g.Key.Address1, 
                                  FirstID = g.First().ID
                                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. You must apply aggregation on field that is not the part of grouping:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(c => new { c.StoreName, c.Address1 }).
                  Select(c => new
                  {
                      ID = c.Min(i => i.ID),
                      c.Key.StoreName,
                      c.Key.Address1
                  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some pseudo code untested but you want something like this

```
storeList.GroupBy(s => new { s.Storename, s.Address1})
         .SelectMany(g => g.First())
         .ToList()
```

Comment: Yeah I was being a jerk,  but your answer looks good plus one

Comment: No need of **OrDefault**, the group always have items.